# Regex, extracting a math expression

Tags: c#, regex

Given the following expression (Example A):

```
10 + hour(@LAST_MODIFIED_DATE-@SUBMIT_DATE) * (@TOTAL_TRANSFERS+@GROUP_TRANSFERS)
```

I'd like to extract just this bit:

```
hour(@LAST_MODIFIED_DATE-@SUBMIT_DATE)
```

Here I can also have something like (Example B):

```
10 + hour(@LAST_MODIFIED_DATE-@SUBMIT_DATE) + (@TOTAL_TRANSFERS+@GROUP_TRANSFERS) + minutes(@LAST_MODIFIED_DATE-@SUBMIT_DATE) + 1000
```

I'd like to extract just these two parts:

```
hour(@LAST_MODIFIED_DATE-@SUBMIT_DATE)
minutes(@LAST_MODIFIED_DATE-@SUBMIT_DATE)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why regex? You need to share what you have coded so far and you need to tell us exactly what is the problem your having with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with something like this:

```
Matches m = Regex.Matches(mathString, "(?:hours?|minutes?|seconds?)\([^)]+\)");

foreach (Match match in m)
    if (match.Value != "")
        doSomething(match.Value);
```